# Transit visa for Germany

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, germany, berlin

I will be traveling from Bangalore, India to Helsinki, Finland.
I have two stops in my journey one at Abu Dhabi and the other at Berlin.
I am an Indian citizen hold a one year student residence permit for Finland.

The airliner suggested that no transit visa is required at Abu Dhabi, But I might require a transit visa at Berlin. 
Is there a requirement of a transit visa for Germany as I will be waiting for my connecting flight for 3 hours at Tegel airport.

Comment: Finland is part of Schengen, so normally a visa to enter Finland will allow you to enter via Germany. What visa do you have for Finland?

Comment: You don't need a visa if you have a regular Finnish residence permit. Berlin Tegel is not well equipped to deal with transit anyway, if you cannot enter the Schengen area (which, again, you should be able to) then the airline has to make special arrangements.

Comment: You write nowhere that you are also arriving at Tegel Airport from Abu Dhabi. Is this the case or do you have to switch airports in Berlin?

Comment: Arrival from Abu Dhabi is almost certainly on one of the Air Berlin / Etihad flights, which all use Tegel

Answer (score 0):

You **NO** need a transit visa in Berlin (check this http://www.india.diplo.de/contentblob/4002756/Daten/3548245/airport_transit.pdf)

> Indian nationals generally require  an airport transit visa for the
> Schengen area. This visa allows a short stop-over at an international
> airport only. Neither leaving the airport’s international transit area
> nor overnight stays in a hotel are  possible. If you need to leave the
> international transit area (i.e. in order to catch a connecting flight
> at another airport to leave the Schengen area), please apply for a
> regular Schengen visa.
>
> Exemptions:
> a) **Indian nationals holding a
> valid visa or residence permit from a member state of the  Schengen**
> area or Bulgaria, Romania, Croatia, Cyprus, Liechtenstein, Ireland,
> UK, Canada,  Japan, USA (except for holders of an US “Advanced Parole
> Document”)
> b) Indian nationals holding a valid residence permit
> Andorra, Monaco or San Marino
> c) Diplomatic passport holders
>
> **generally *do not require* an airport transit visa.**

Comment: Warning! This seems to only apply to people with a US residency permit.

Comment: Sorry, modified my answer

Comment: Given that Finland is part of Schengen and the OP should already have a visa to enter does he really need a transit visa for Berlin in Germany which is also part of Schengen area?

Comment: @Karlson: No, this answer is actually quite misleading. Since the flight from Berlin to Helsinki is intra-schengen, the OP will have to go through regular immigration control in Berlin to enter the Schengen area. Staying in international transit (for which a transit visa may have been required) is not possible. Since a residence permit from a Schengen country gives you (for all practical purposes) the same right to travel within the Schengen area as EU/EEC citizens, no further visa is required.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo My point exactly

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo  It's not misleading. It's a document of Germany Embassy in India. Usually, indian people need transit visa. EXEMPTION - is people who already have valid visa or residence permit - so they NO need a visa.

Comment: @MikkaRin: What is unclear in the explanation I already gave? It is irrelevant if a transit visa is required or not, because OP is not in transit, but has to enter the Schengen area in Berlin.